# Wordpress Template (Probabaly Not Going To Be A Template) That Is Only Used By One Page

Tags: wordpress

I am just learning the basics of WordPress and would like to know how to do something.

I understand the concept of templates.  I can have multiple pages that run of a single template so that there is a consistent look and feel across the site.

In the php file, I declare say product.php as a template with some code like:

```
/*
Template Name: Products
*/
```

This then becomes available as a template option for me in the admin area when I create a new page.

However what I am struggling to understand is the following.

Some pages are completely unique in their structure.  I don't want them to run off a template.  I guess the main reason behind this is that an end user may accidentally override the template in the admin section by mistake and I would like to keep this to a minimum wherever it is possible.

What also confuses me is with such a page do you still need to create the page within the WP admin section, or, using whatever method is needed, will it automatically appear under the pages section?

Can someone please explain how this would be done in WordPress.

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope someone else finds this useful.  I've not tried it yet but I just found out that if you create a file with the name convention page-.php then this will automatically load for the page with that slug.

I knew it had to be possible.  Thanks for all your contributions.

Answer (score 1):

Every page in WordPress is going to be running off some sort-of template. If it didn't have a template then you'd be out of luck because then.. where would your data go? In order for things to not be broken by your clients you create a template so that they are simply editing text, etc and not dabbling with the structure of the page (we'll leave that to you in your creation of the templates).

I've had sites with up to ten different templates before. Simply because certain pages do have a unique information architecture. Don't be afraid to add a template if you need one because sometimes there really is no other way to go.

Not sure if this is the best advice - but if I was honestly that worried my client was going to start messing with the page template I'd just write some javascript that would check if they're an admin and if they are not an admin to hide the elements that allow them to change the template.

In the instance that you don't want users to be able to see certain templates, or you don't want them to be able to see specific template files you can place this in your functions.php:

```
function add_jquery_admin() {
    global $parent_file;

    // if editing page in WP admin and user is not an admin
    if ( isset( $_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['action'] == 'edit' && isset( $_GET['post'] ) && $parent_file == 'edit.php' && !current_user_can('manage_options')) {

        // remove the options for each of the templates on the template select element
        echo '
        <script>
            var q = jQuery.noConflict();
            q(function(){
                q("#page_template option[value=\"template-file-name-1.php\"]").remove();
                q("#page_template option[value=\"template-file-name-2.php\"]").remove();
                q("#page_template option[value=\"template-file-name-3.php\"]").remove();
            });
        </script>
        ';

        // get current post id
        $post_id = $_GET['post'];

        // if the post id 123, 1234, or 12345 
        if ( $post_id == 123 || $post_id == 1234 || $post_id == 12345 ) { // if on one of these post ids disable the template selector

            // disable the page template select element
            echo '
            <script>
            var j = jQuery.noConflict();
            j(function(){
                j("#page_template").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
            });
            </script>
            ';
        }
    }
}

add_filter('admin_head', 'add_jquery_admin');
```

I didn't test but I think it should be okay. You'll just need to switch out the template file names where you see these -- `q("#page_template option[value=\"template-file-name-1.php\"]").remove();`.

Also, you'll need to gather the unique post id for each of the pages you don't want them to see the template select element on. You'll be able to get that by looking at the URL - it will say something like `post=200` in the URL. You're going to put these in here -- `if ( $post_id == 123 || $post_id == 1234 || $post_id == 12345 )`.

I know this seems sort-of cumbersome, but I really couldn't think of or find any other solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've used other basic CMSs and what I am trying to acheive is possible in those.  I agree that it will still be a template of sorts, but I would like it to be one that the client is unable to change because there will be no other page with that structure, and therefore it does not need to be selectable.

Comment: I provided some additional code that will make it so only an admin will be able to see/change to certain templates while in the admin. You'd need to create them an account as an Editor user for this to work properly. Also required would be plugging in some values from your particular WordPress install.

Comment: Hi Kyle, loving the effort so I've marked you up but I found a more elegant solution for this.  Top man for the code though.  I will give that a go too, to see if it works.

Comment: What did you come up with? I'm genuinely interested in case I run across a similar scenario. Sharing is caring! :)

Comment: Hi Kyle, I did share the answer below but here is the official line from the wordpress codex 'page-{slug}.php - If the page slug is recent-news, WordPress will look to use page-recent-news.php'.  Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Just like kyle says. Do it with the page templates. Nothing to lose their. After creating the php file you can add the page by the wp-admin panel.

Comment: There is potentially something to lose.  The end-user might change the template for that page, or use this 'unique' template accidentally for another page.

Comment: it's true that the enduser could use it for another page. But he can't change the template. You could allow him to only insert text (with the WYSIWYG editor) to be shown in a place where you defined it in the template.

Comment: I guess what I want is a template that a page uses but then to hide it in the admin panel?  Maybe that is what I am after?

Comment: if you do not want the page to show up in the admin panel make sure that
 /*
Template Name: NAME_HERE
*/
isn't in the page template. Then it won't show up in the admin panel.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think that would be of any use to anyone.  A template that could never be selected?